# How can I connect IdentityUser with Recipe in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, one-to-many

I want to create One-To-Many relationship in ASP.NET.CORE MVC, between IdentityUser and Recipe. When i try to assign ApplicationUserId to curently logged in userId it gets null value. When i open AspNetUsers in server explorer it doens't have Recipes property. I dont't  know how to get it to work properly

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
 namespace WebApplication.Models
    {
        public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
           
          public List<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**RecipeController.cs**

```
    namespace WebApplication.Controllers
    {
        public class RecipeController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;
            private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
            private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
            public RecipeController( ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
            {
                _signInManager = signInManager;
                _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
                _userManager = userManager;
            }
    
            public IActionResult Create()
            {
    
                var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("RecipeName,RecipeContent")] Recipe recipe)
            {
                var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
                    recipe.ApplicationUserId = userId;
                    _applicationDbContext.Recipes.Add(recipe);
                    await _applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return View(recipe);


        }
     
    }
}
```

**Recipe.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RecipeName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RecipeContent { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Database schema]

Comment: When you say "[...] curently logged in userId it gets null value" do you mean that `var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);` is null? If so, are you using cookie authentication or how do you identify users? Please share your Startup.cs

Comment: I have added startup.cs

Comment: Have you tried putting an `[Authorize]` attribute on your `Create` route?

Comment: Hi @KamilGórny, which value is null?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe This will work for you.
In your Sql Server, execute these commands

```
ALTER TABLE Recipes
ADD UserId nvarchar(450)

ALTER TABLE Recipes
ADD FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES AspNetUsers(Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the official Doc ?

[Official Ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Did you update your ApplicationDbCOntext Class to derive from IdentityDbContext

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   public virtual DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

In startup.cs in service add this as well

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultUI();
```

There's no need to override OnModelCreating in the ApplicationDbContext class. EF Core maps the CustomTag property by convention. However, the database needs to be updated to create a new CustomTag column. To create the column, add a migration, and then update the database as described in Identity and EF Core Migrations.

It means do in the Package manager console off visual studio:

```
PM> Add-Migration

PM> Update-Database
```

**Update 1:**
I get what you mean it doesn't create a field with the foreign key. I managed to create a foreign key in it but it didn't create the other table in the initial create. Maybe this will help you.

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Recipe Recipes { get; set; }
}
```

Respond to your Own question If you find a solution I'm facing the same issue more or less I will continue to investigate and Update my post later If I find a Solution.

[image]

Well It works with what I update above I have screenshot confirmation. I made it work on my database. Let me know if it works for you.